# PHP PDO Order by Fiedname values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

just recenlty convert by `PHP PDO Query`, i am a little confused with `ORDER BY`

i have 2 fieldnames and values i want to ORDER BY this was my old data i need to convert to PDO

QUESTION : how do i use `ORDER BY` in PDO

```
$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `supplies` ORDER BY field(citname,'Dejan Vemic','MitkoEzio','Sebatay','Ash2Ash','Dexter Sinister','dracoolinho','KALE Podgorica','Omerta NK','Pobor','Rachsuchtig','Snake0307','SrpskaCG','Vojvoda1389') ASC, field(day,'Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday')");
```

if someone who please help, this is my current statement

```
$sql = 'SELECT citid, citname, worked, rankpoints, supplyamount, wassupplied, date, day FROM supplies';
```

Comment: PDO is just the interface to the database server. The queries don't change unless you're using prepared statements. Why can't you use your original query?

Comment: tip - php strings can span multiple lines, making code more readable.

Comment: i want to move away from mysqli and use PDO and i have already tried using ORDER BY as mysqli in PDO and it doesnt work, with PDO all i know its about BINDING or something

Comment: I reworded your question to help it get it of hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not binding variables you can use [query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)
Note that `ASC` is default and is not required.

```
 $sql ="SELECT * FROM `supplies` ORDER BY field(citname,'Dejan Vemic','MitkoEzio',
'Sebatay','Ash2Ash','Dexter Sinister','dracoolinho','KALE Podgorica','Omerta NK',
'Pobor','Rachsuchtig','Snake0307','SrpskaCG','Vojvoda1389'), 
 field(day,'Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday',
 'Saturday')":

foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    print $row['citid'] . "\t";
    print $row['citname'] . "\t";
    //ETC
}
```

Comment: i need to order by field value within a field in my own order, so it works the same way ? as i want to do the following in PHP PDO `field(citname,'value 1','value'), field(day,'Sunday','Monday','Tuesday')");`

Comment: @user2517479 Changed answer to address comment. If you want the hold on the question to be lifted I advise you to EDIT it. The edit I did would probably help.

Comment: thank you i forgot that i can use different statements in PDO as it supports many, so i now have a mix of PDO and standard sql statement